# Fazer uma assistente pesosal

Tags: python

Olá, eu estou desenvolvendo um assistente pessoal no Python, porém eu gostaria de usar um processo parecido com o do "Ok Google", onde quando eu falo a frase, o programa é executado. Ou seja, quando eu falar algo similar a "Ok Google" o software executa.
O programa já está todo feito. Eu só queria saber como abrir o programa quando eu "chamar" ele.

Comment: Você chegou à implementar algum código?

Comment: Para tal feito use uma API de [reconhecimento de fala](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeira coisa que você tem que fazer é instalar no python uma bibliotéca de reconhecimento de voz, no caso desse exemplo a biblioteca é [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/).

Para instalar:

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Depois de instalada de uma lida em sua [documentação](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst)

```
# importa o módulo de reconhecimento de voz
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtém o audio do microfone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Diga alguma coisa...")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# reconhece a fala usando o Google Speech Recognition.
# o método r.recognize_google(audio) está usando a chave padrão do Google Speech Recognition
# para usar sua chave use a sobrecarga r.recognize_google(audio, chave) onde
# chave é uma string contendo sua chave para a API Google Speech Recognition
try:
    print("Você disse: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError ue:
    print("Houve um erro: {0}".format(ue))
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Falha na requisição ao serviço Google Speech Recognition: {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: Eu já implementei o `speech_recognition as sr`. Eu só quero que o programa execute quando eu falar "Ok Google" por exemplo.
Como se eu "chamasse" o programa para ele abrir quando eu falar.

Comment: Mais ai você tem que configurar no sistema operacional. Se for Windows você tem que configurar a Cortana, se for Linux você tem que configurar o Sirius, se for no MacOS tem que configurar a Siri e se for Android é o Android Assistent. Não tem nada a ver com Python.

Comment: Em python você criar um serviço para usar o listener `listen_in_background(source, callback)`.